# Laurent series for exponential function with powers shifted by $1 \over 2$

Tags: calculus, functions

After reading about [Fractional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) I'm trying to derive an expression for exponential with powers shifted by $1 \over 2$. Presumably, applying half-derivative operator to exponential function power series would leave it intact. However, neither

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {x^{k-{1 \over 2}} \over \Gamma(k+{1 \over 2})} $

nor simplified form

$ {1 \over \sqrt \pi} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {4^k {k!}  {x^{k-{1 \over 2}} } \over (2k)!} $

render the exponent. I tried the Laurent series for the exponent

$e^{x} = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} {x^k  \over \Gamma(k+1)}$

as a starting point, which leads to

$e^{x} =^?  \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} {x^{k-{1 \over 2}} \over \Gamma(k+{1 \over 2})} $

but Wolfram Alpha insists that the series doesn't converge.

At this point I give up. Is there Laurent "series" of this kind for exponential?

Comment: Note that $\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac12\right)=\sqrt\pi\frac{(2n)!}{4^nn!}$ for $n\ge0$, and $\Gamma\!\left(-n+\frac12\right)=\sqrt\pi\frac{(-4)^nn!}{(2n)!}$ for $n\gt0$.

Comment: Fixed the sloppy substitution of $\Gamma(k+{1 \over 2})$, thank you. Now, I'm getting the same evaluation of the sum in wolfram alpha. However, it is the exponent multiplied by error function: ${e^x erf(\sqrt {x} )} + {1 \over {\sqrt {\pi x}}}$. Summing from $0$, not $-\infty$